# REGEXP in Ruby to check if a word has more than a letter

Tags: ruby, regex

I already solved with if else and count, but I'm really what to know if you have some solution to check if a word has more than a character.

I want to check if any string given just have to be a, b or c. It will fail if it's aaa, ab, cc, dd.

Like I said before I already have a solution but using if's I would like to use regexp with ruby.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your question needs some clarity. Will the string only contain one letter or more than one? Will there be any delimiters like spaces? Should "a b" fail?

Comment: Add your solution using `if`. It'll be easier for us to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match 'a', 'b' or 'c', but nothing else, you can use this regex:

```
/^[abc]$/
```

To check if a string is empty or contains anything *other* than a single 'a', 'b' or 'c', this should do the trick:

```
/^$|[^abc]|.{2,}/
```

Depending on what characters you want to allow, you may need to replace the `[abc]` and `[^abc]` parts. For example, allowing the whole (lower-case) alphabet would require the following character classes: `[a-z]`, `[^a-z]`.

Answer (score 0):

This one would do the trick for matching only one character:

```
^[a-zA-Z]$
```

if you want to match no characters as well, just use:

```
^[a-zA-Z]?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lengthGreaterThan1?(str)
  if str =~ /.{2,}|^$/
    return "yes"
  else
    return "no"
  end
end
```

Assuming that you are passing a string to this function with no delimiters for words, it will only match strings that are exactly length one.

Note that `/^$/` matches blank strings and the string "a b" fails.